# Qual é o comando editor de texto do linux que posso ver saída em tempo real?

Tags: linux, log, editor-de-texto, vim

Qual é o comando editor de texto do linux que posso ver saída em tempo real?

Por exemplo quero dar um "vim" no access log do meu apache quero ver os GET entrando no log em tempo real qual é o parâmetro que eu uso ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode utilizar o:

```
tail -f nome_do_arquivo
```

ou:

```
tailf nome_do_arquivo
```

Comment: Perfeito obrigado!

Comment: Precisando é só perguntar!

Answer (score 1):

`less file.log` e depois que abrir o arquivo  `shift+f` fará o mesmo papel do tail. Além disso ainda te permite navegar no arquivo, fazer buscas, etc. Enfim, é um "vi read-only". Mais detalhes veja [neste artigo](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-less-command-10-tips-for-effective-navigation).